# Cannot make file readonly in Java 8 on linux

Tags: java, java-8, junit4

I'm trying to write a unit test to make sure IOExceptions are handled in the code correctly. The tested method accepts a path (String) as a sole parameter and writes "Hello World" into the specified file. I need to make sure the code catches all exceptions which can be thrown in an attempt to write the file. Unfortunately, I cannot mock `BufferedWriter` so I'm guessing the next best thing is to simulate the inability to write to the target file, e.g. by making it read-only.

I have a very simple code:

```java
public class MyClass {
  public static void main(String[] args){

    Path path = Paths.get("my-file.txt");
    try {
      Files.createFile(path);
      File file = new File(path.toString());
      file.setReadOnly();
    } catch (IOException ignored){}

    try {
      Files.write(path, "Hello World".getBytes());
    } catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

This works as expected on my Windows machine, i.e. a `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` is thrown, however, I cannot get the code to work on linux

```
# uname -a
Linux 9373fa9a374f 4.14.294-150.533.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Sep 29 00:51:31 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_342"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_342-8u342-b07-0ubuntu1~22.04-b07)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.342-b07, mixed mode)
```

The result of `file.setReadOnly()` is true on both Windows and Linux/ubuntu but on linux it seems to make no difference (no exception is thrown).

I've tried to set the file permissions via `PosixFilePermission` and, once again, reading the files permissions back shows `OWNER_READ` (using `r--------`), but `Files.write` happily executes without any exceptions.

```java
    try {
      Files.setPosixFilePermissions(path, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("r--------"));
      Files.write(path, "Hello World".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Any ideas how I can set things up so that `Files.write` throws an exception. Or is there a better way to test the io exception handling?

Thank you

Comment: Which user are you running this as?

Comment: `root` in a docker container (in CI/CD pipeline), is that the issue?

Comment: root can always read and write any file, ignoring any permissions set on that file. Try it on the command line (as root): `touch file; chmod a-rwx file; echo 'still changing' > file; cat file`

Comment: damn, I really should have thought of that ... i guess I can "hack" that using `chattr +i file`

Comment: or not ... docker has `CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE` disabled by default and I don't have access to the `docker-compose.yml`, damn. ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522621/in-docker-chattr-operation-not-permitted-while-setting-flags-on-file/522633#522633